# Filling in random positions in a huge 2D array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, 2d

Is a there a neat algorithm that I can use to fill in random positions in a huge 2D *n* x *n* array with *m* number of integers without filling in an occupied position? Where [image: nformula], and [image: mformula]

Kind of like this pseudo code:

```
int n;
int m;

void init(int new_n, int new_m) {
    n = new_n;
    m = new_m;
}
void create_grid() {
    int grid[n][n];

    int x, y;
    for(x = 1; x <= n; x ++) {
        for(y = 1; y <= n; y ++) {
            grid[x][y] = 0;
        }
    }

    populate_grid(grid);
}

void populate_grid(int grid[][]) {
    int i = 1;
    int x, y;

    while(i <= m) {
        x = get_pos();
        y = get_pos();

        if(grid[x][y] == 0) {
            grid[x][y] = i;
            i ++;
        }
    }
}

int get_pos() {
    return random() % n + 1;
}
```

... but more efficient for bigger n's and m's. Specially if m is bigger and more positions are being occupied, it would take longer to generate a random position that isn't occupied.

Comment: Do you call n²=900 "huge" ?

Comment: Notice that your code only flags m-1 cells. Can you see why ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust It could be bigger. Please explain.

Comment: One way you might approach this would be to generate a list of all of the possible positions, pick a random one to set to 1, remove that option from the list, then repeat as long as you would like. Then each position can only be picked once, so you avoid the possibility of choosing the same position more than once

Comment: Yes, there are neat algorithms to generate random positions that don't repeat...   But since you're only filling 10% of cells, your method is faster.  You would use a "neat algorithm" if, for example, you didn't have the memory to remember all the previously filled cells

Comment: @MattTimmermans I would generally agree with you, but it seems the potential problem space isn't fully described here. He specifically mentioned the potential for having `m` be larger and therefore filling a higher percent of the spaces.

Comment: I made a mistake of putting it as 10%. It should be possible for *m* to be 90% of the entire grid.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the filling factor really gets large, you shouldn't worry about hitting occupied positions.

Assuming for instance that half of the cells are already filled, you have 50% of chances to first hit a filled cell; and 25% to hit two filled ones in a row; 12.5% of hitting three... On average, it takes... two attempts to find an empty place ! (More generally, if there is only a fraction 1/M of free cells, the average number of attempts raises to M.)

If you absolutely want to avoid having to test the cells, you can work by initializing an array with the indexes of the free cells. Then instead of choosing a random cell, you choose a random entry in the array, between 1 and L (the lenght of the list, initially N²).

After having chosen an entry, you set the corresponding cell, you move the last element in the list to the random position, and set L= L-1. This way, the list of free positions is kept up-to-date.

Note the this process is probably less efficient than blind attempts.

Answer (score 0):

To generate pseudo-random positions without repeats, you can do something like this:

```
for (int y=0; y<n; ++y) {
    for(int x=0; x<n; ++x) {
        int u=x,v=y;
        u = (u+hash(v))%n;
        v = (v+hash(u))%n;
        u = (u+hash(v))%n;
        output(u,v);
    }
 }
```

for this to work properly, hash(x) needs to be a good pseudo-random hash function that produces positive numbers that won't overflow when you add to a number between 0 and n.

This is a version of the Feistel structure (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher), which is commonly used to make cryptographic ciphers like DES.

The trick is that each step like `u = (u+hash(v))%n;` is invertible -- you can get your original `u` back by doing `u = (u-hash(v))%n` (I mean you *could* if the `%` operator worked with negative numbers the way everyone wishes it did)

Since you can invert the operations to get the original `x,y` back from each `u,v` output, each distinct `x,y` MUST produce a distinct `u,v`.